# Prove $R$ is not an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Given $R = \{(1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 5) \}$ over $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, an assignment is asking me to prove that $R^{-1} \circ R$ is **NOT** an equivalence relation.

I'm having a lot of trouble with this because I'm pretty much convinced that 
$R^{-1} \circ R$ **IS** an equivalence relation.

$R^{-1} \circ R = \{ (1,1),(1,2),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2),(2,4),(3,3),(4,1),(4,2),(4,4),(5,5) \}$

$R^{-1} \circ R$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. Therefore, it is an equivalence relation.

Did I calculate $R^{-1} \circ R$  wrong, or is there something wrong with my understanding of the concept of an equivalence relation? Or maybe there's a mistake in the assignment itself. What is happening here?

Comment: Why is $\left(3,3\right)\in R^{-1}\circ R$?

Comment: $ (3,4) ∈ R^{-1}$ and $(4,3) ∈ R$. Therefore $(3,3) ∈ R^{-1} ◦ R. $

Comment: My guess is you're computing the composition of relations backwards. Specifically, $(x, y) \in R^{-1} \circ R$ should hold when there exists $a$ such that $(x, a) \in R$ and $(a, y) \in R^{-1}$, i.e., $(x, a)$ and $(y, a)$ are both in $R$. This notation looks weird for relations, but it makes sense when you consider functions to be a kind of relation.

Comment: Problem solved, that's right, I was doing it backwards.